# how to parse an xml file with python without hardcoding

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have an xml file that I need to parse without harcoding the attributes given:

```
<test_machines name="Mac1">
    <ip_address>192.168.0.0</ip_address>
    <operating_system type="OS X" version="10.10.5">OS X version=10.10.5</operating_system>
    <path_to>path</path_to>
</test_maschines>
```

I was able to parse the file but hadrcoded the names of nodes like ip_machines and also hardcoding the attribute names like type="OS X". 
I need to find a way to parse the file without doing any of that stuff.
How do I achieve this?
Thans to all in advance!

Comment: Python comes with at least TWO highly capable XML parser implementations.  They do not require that you hardcode anything.  Did you read the documentation?  I suggest you start there.

Answer (score 0):

Python has both [builtin functions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) and very powerful third party libraries like [lxml](http://lxml.de/) with same API to parse xml files and much more. Check them out by clicking on the links.